# How to write sql query in wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to run sql query on wordpress.

```
$sql = "SELECT  description FROM expression WHERE expressionid='1'";
```

This above code is sql query its working fine in normal php page.

I added this same code in wordpress page

```
$mylink = $numerology->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $numerology->expression WHERE id = 1" );
```

This above wordpress code is not working in my page . How to write mysql query code in wordpress page.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available on pagination, search on Google. But having said that, you can use this pagination script in your project, [https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination](https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination). The usage documentation is pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: Can you be more precise? How is it not working? Do you get an error message? Can you try and print out `$wpdb->last_error` (or better, in your case, `$numerology->last_error`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the example:

```
$description_data = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT description FROM expression WHERE expressionid='1'
");
```